# Work out what characters are allowed in a field with a VAM:RegexValidator?

Tags: vb.net, validation

I am investigating an issue with regards to a textbox rejecting user input.  In this case the error message is: 'The note was found to contain a possible credit card PAN.'

Now obviously this is a custom validator but I am enable to find where it tells me what characters ARE allowed?  In debug I entered a note containing no numbers and when the validators are initialized, these variables have the value below:

valNoteContainsPAN.Expression = Me.PANRegEx

value = (\d*)45367{13,15}(?!\d)

I'm assuming this is blocking numbers of certain lengths?  How can I find out how to actually read and understand the above?  Google is proving fruitless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody in the same jam as me this website proved extremely helpful:

http://regexhero.net/

It essentially allowed me to enter the coded restriction field and test what would be accepted as well as explaining what each piece of the command actually meant.

This website: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html  Also gave more of the theory behind it to help me understand what was going on.